# Half image and And Half color with cutting how can i design this type of design

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

[please guide me how can I make this type of design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12MWT.jpg)

I try to make it by bootstrap but failed to make it because I have no idea how to make this type of background please guide me proper way to design it..

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by stacking multiple background images.  In this case, I've used a linear gradient (gradients are background images in CSS) to create the triangle in the right corner.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(140deg, transparent 70%, darkviolet 70%),    
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/237/500/300);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: right;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 2rem;
}

nav {
 background-color: gold;
 padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>Example Nav Here</nav>
</header>
```